# Facebook api method

Tags: php

Actually,I am using function

```
FB.ui({
method: 'apprequests',
message: 'A request especially for one person.'

});
```

for sending friend request for our web application .it is working on my domain (http://policy-party.the-appideas.com/version2). but not working on clients domain (http://www.policyparty.com/) domains are on different  server neither it;s giving any error. it showing only popup but friendlist are not loading on that popup.